# Does installing Ubuntu delete all my data in other disks too?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I already have Windows 10 installed and want to replace it with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but I have two drives: one SSD, one hard drive.

Will installing Ubuntu erase the data on my both disks, or only the one on which I install Ubuntu, and how can choose in which disk I want to install Ubuntu on?

Comment: I have done a number of QA-test installs of *impish* (what will be 21.10 on release) and *focal* (what will be 20.04.3 on release) in recent days; including on systems that I actually use.  Yes an install can overwrite and destroy everything on your system (with it replaced by the new system you just installed), but if you use the correct options nothing will be erased (my last test was *upgrade via re-install*).  It's all up to you options you use. I tend to use *Something else* (or *Manual Partitioning*) so I have full control over what is done, but it's your choice; you control what occurs.

Comment: FYI:    I did a QA-test install on a system I *cherish* and sure do not want to lose. I had no backups of that system I use (*but I know I can re-create everything on it; it'll just take time*!)  but I'd recommend for sure having good backups of anything you value. I'd done the same install only recently (do it *regularly*) where it just re-installs a *fresh* system onto the existing system; no user files are touched! which is why I call it *upgrade via re-install*; I run the QA-test install instead of updating the system... but if you're new at installing systems - backup before you start.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you make major system changes, make sure your standard backup is current.

If UEFI, both Windows & Ubuntu/grub reset boot order to have their system as first in UEFI. You have to then change order, if new order is not what you want.

If BIOS, you only have one MBR per device. So you need to use grub to boot Windows. And then  you may need Windows repair/recovery flash drive to temporarily restore Windows boot loader, if Windows issues.

Windows turns on fast start up/hibernation with some updates. If Windows is hibernated, then grub will not boot it. You have to directly boot Windows & turn off hibernation.

If BIOS, Windows is known to update partition table and forget to include any logical ext4 partitions, since Windows 7. Partition is still there & you just have to restore entry into partition table.

Also if you change boot mode in Windows it changes partitioning, erasing drive. Normally UEFI is gpt and BIOS is MBR. So installing another system, may change partitioning which erases drive.

With multiple drives or multiple installs, best to only use Something Else.
I prefer to partition in advance with gparted and use Something Else to choose(change) new partition(s). You can partition during install, but does not seem quite as easy to me.

Comment: Good! So as the OQ asks, it's *not* Ubuntu; rather, it's *Windows* that will delete the Ubuntu partition. :-)

Comment: Ubuntu does have install selections that say use entire drive. Because Windows has called partitions as "drives", users may think a "D:" drive may not be be erased with a full drive install. Some have posted they just wanted to erase the c: drive & keep data on d: drive. So users must understand a drive is the entire physical device, and if instructions say erase entire drive that is what it will do. Windows & then user incorrect understanding of partitions vs drive cause Linux installs to erase partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu won't delete your data *if you make the correct selections*.

However, humans are notorious for our typos and misunderstandings of clearly-written instructions. We may blame the installer, but the fault is still ours.

- Advice: If you truly value your data, *back it up*. Installing a new Operating System is **inherently risky**.
- Advice: Spin up a Virtual Machine on your current OS. Practice installing Ubuntu onto that VM a couple times. Make your mistakes there. Learn which settings you need to keep a sample data set intact.

Comment: Is it still the case that the first Windows Update (after the dual boot install) breaks booting from Ubuntu?

Comment: If UEFI, both Windows & Ubuntu/grub reset boot order to have their system as first in UEFI. And Windows turns on fast start up/hibernation. If Windows is hibernated, then grub will not boot it. If BIOS, Windows is known to update partition table and forget to include any logical ext4 partitions, since Windows 7. Partition is still there & you just have to restore entry into partition table.  Also if you change boot mode in Windows it changes partitioning, erasing drive.  Normally UEFI is gpt and BIOS is MBR, Best to always have good backups.

Comment: @oldfred That would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has clear instructions on how to install. It gives choices to either erase the drive and install Ubuntu full system, or select a partition if you have an existing OS.

Make sure you’re keen on that when installing.